# Can I add to map[] values concurrently?

Tags: go

I am adding to a `map[[]byte]int` concurrently from multiple `go routines`.

Will I get a runtime panic for doing this?

I don't care if data in the `map` becomes corrupted, because it can't , I am only inserting a value once and never again. But I can't get a runtime panic because the whole porgram will abort.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/50c5042047be3af36e7bb478435093ea45e8f1f0) go would actively try to detect map misuse, like what you suggest, and panic. If you need concurrent map use sync.Map or guard with Mutex.

Comment: You will care if the map is corrupted if it has corrupted other parts of your heap. [There are no benign data races](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong), just synchronize access.

Comment: @JimB I thought golang runs go routines sequentially inside the runtime, so adding a value to a map, though officially not recommended, in the reality race condition won't happen. That's my hypotesis.

Comment: Goroutines run concurrently on a system with multiple CPUs.

Answer (score 3):

Maps are not safe for concurrent writes. Use a mutex to access it safely.

Furthermore `map[[]byte]int` is not valid -- the key must be comparable. Slices are not comparable.

Comment: I know they are not safe in regard to the values, but are they safe at the level of runtime?

Comment: I would not count on that. What use-case is this where you don't care about the map becoming corrupt?

Comment: a lookup table, when the value is only inserted once

Comment: @Nulik, if you don't synchronize read/write access to a map your program will eventually panic. And that goes for all values in Go, not just maps.

Comment: Even if the program did not panic and crash, a corrupt lookup table would not be very useful, would it.

Comment: it is useful, the value is cryptographically verified by next process, so if there is some error, nothing bad is going to happen

Comment: When you verify and realise it's corrupt, then what use is it? Synchronise access, or don't use a map.

Comment: @jsageryd the program will exit and I will restart it, but that is not supposed to happen all the time